# Выражение "понаехали тут"

Tags: лексика

Существует ли глагол "понаехать"? Как можно объяснить значение выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НАЕХАТЬ, св. 2. Разг. **Приехать, прибыть в каком-л. (обычно большом) количестве.** К вечеру наехали гости. 3. Разг. Приехать **внезапно, неожиданно**. Наехали ревизоры. Наехала комиссия. 4. на кого. Жарг. С помощью угроз, шантажа требовать сделать, выполнить что-л. На меня наехали какие-то бандиты, требуют денег.

ПОНАЕХАТЬ,  св. Разг. **Постепенно наехать в большом количестве**.  В город понаехало множество беженцев.

**Все варианты разговорные, это свидетельствует об особом (переосмысленном) значении предлогов НА и В.**

**Предлог НА:** неожиданно, большой массой наехать на кого-то или что-то, как бы "накрыть сверху".

**Предлог ПО:** он отвечает за "дозированный по времени" наезд: да, наехали в большом количестве, но в течение определенного времени.

"Дважды разговорное" слово  "понаехали" выражает особое неприятие  ситуации, в том числе с ироническим смыслом.

Comment: А почему нельзя с _неопределённым_ временем? Понаехали (когда-то) и заселили территорию. _Все груши попадали с дерева._ (неизвестно когда)

Comment: Предлог ПО обозначает растянутость процесс во времени: груши не сразу все упали,  а падали какое-то время.

Comment: Про груши можно, конечно, домыслить, что они упали не все сразу, а падали по мере индивидуального созревания. Но как быть с ситуацией "все дружно попадали со смеху" (от одной и той же шутки) - имеет ли здесь значение, что кто-то "коснулся пола" чуть раньше?

Comment: А как надо написать: "все дружно упали со смеху" ?  Так что если даже дружно, то в любом случае  индивидуально.  Здесь, а также во всех других ситуациях,  проявляется РАСПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение предлога ПО.

Comment: Написать надо как и написано. Действительно, каждый реагирует индивидуально, но с распределением во времени или очерёдностью это не связано: смысл утверждения лишь в том, что нечто произошло и с одним, и с другим, и с любым кого ни возьми из общей группы.

Comment: Из словаря. Приставка ПО 5. Вносит зн. распространения действия на все или многие объекты, везде или во многих местах, а также охвата действием, состоянием всех или многих субъектов. Попрятать, побывать, повыбить, повыдергать, понабросать, побиться, повыбраться, повыходить, помёрзнуть, попадать.

Comment: В словах попрятать (множественные сущности) и побывать (напр. в конкретном месте) роли у "по-" разные (во втором случае выражается законченность действия, факт его совершения). В случае "побиться" (биться в течение какого-то времени) - что-то третье; если о посуде - то о частичном (местами, слегка и пр.) её разбитии. Вряд ли такие обобщения могут быть универсальны.

Comment: Одним из значением приставки  ПО является дистрибутивное (распределительное)  значение, когда действие совершается в разное время, разными лицами, в несколько приемов  и т.д. Иногда приставка присоединяется к другой приставке: понавезти, понанести, повыталкивать, повыгонять. (Сюда же относится глагол понаехали). Например: понанести - постепенно нанести.  Поэтому понаехали - это постепенно приехали в большом количестве. И это всё. Именно это значение мы считываем с морфемного состава слова.

Answer (score 2):

Не должны подобные слова (а их достаточно много) вызывать сомнений. Общий смысл, придаваемый таким глаголам элементом "по-" состоит в массовости действия: оно должно совершаться в одиночку *каждым из многих* производителей (действия), количество которых остаётся неопределённым. Множественность может проистекать и от объектов воздействия.

> Понаехали красноамейцы, сначала понакупили в деревне водки, а потом
>   как понабежали на зажиточных крестьян - много народу поубивали и
>   пораскулачили!

В большинстве случаев такие глаголы согласованы с множественным числом существительного (иногда - числительного), но  в применении к собирательным понятиям ("народ", "контингент" и пр.) могут сочетаться и с единственным числом.

> Весь этот понаехавший сброд попрятался в подвалы.

Answer (score 1):

У ещё не поехавшего крышей Задорнова:

Коридорная: - Вы тут что? - Ответ (адекватный, имхо): - Мы тут вот.

Это относительно употребления  указательного "тут". Поэтому у "фразеологизма" родом из начала 90-х "тут" можно отобрать (в смысле попытки объяснить значение; а нетути никакого особого значения у тута, тут - это местообитание произнесения).

А глагол "понаехать" запросто обитает и в старых и в новых словарях.

Ушаков:

> ПОНАЕ́ХАТЬ, понаеду, понаедешь (разг.). Наехать (в 3 знач.)
>   постепенно, мало-помалу. Понаехали гости. К нам понаехало много
>   народу.

Малый академический словарь русского языка (с примерами употребления из литературы!):

> Постепенно наехать (во 2 знач.) в большом количестве.
>
> ***Из Москвы понаехали гости.*** Чехов, Письмо Н. М. Линтваревой, 6 апр. 1892.
>
> ***В город понаехало множество беженцев.*** Гайдар, Школа.

[**источник**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-52698.htm)

Comment: Вспомнился случай из армии. Наччасти обнаружил рядового прикорнувшего в тамбуре и проспавшего отбой. Грохот двери разбудил последнего, и тот вскочил , спросонья отдавая честь.  Нач.части "Товарищ рядовой, что вы туту делаете?" Несчастный: "Товарищ командир, я тут..это.. м... н-нах-хожусь!"  Начальник по всей видимости от такого "завис" и до конца смены ничего ни у кого не спрашивал. Кажется, тот же Задорнов придумал глагол "недоперевыпить"